# HashMap stream with criteria Math.abs(double)

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, key-value

Please help me learn navigating between maps. I've a hashmap of Map<String, List>

```
sourceHashMapFind=.put("AAA", Arrays.asList(-5.6, 7.9, 5.7, 6.3));
sourceHashMapFind=.put("BBB", Arrays.asList(0.6, 5.8, 6.9, 8.0));
sourceHashMapFind=.put("CCC", Arrays.asList(0.5, 5.6, 6.9, 8.0));
```

And I would like to generate another map of ==>  HashMap<String, Double>

Here's my criteria. If absolute value of the 0 position is greater than 1. -->  then save the Key and Value into the new queryPositions hashmap.  Thank you in advance!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, List<Double>> sourceHashMapFind = new HashMap<>();

        sourceHashMapFind.put("AAA", Arrays.asList(-5.6, 7.9, 5.7, 6.3));
        sourceHashMapFind.put("BBB", Arrays.asList(0.6, 5.8, 6.9, 8.0));
        sourceHashMapFind.put("CCC", Arrays.asList(0.5, 5.6, 6.9, 8.0));

        
        
         HashMap<String, Double> queryPositions = sourceHashMapFind.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                .filter(entry -> Math.abs(entry.getValue().get(0)) > 1.0)
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> entry.getValue()));
    }
    
    
}
```

**Here's run output**

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.Map<K,U>
    upper bounds: java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Double>,java.lang.Object
    at P2020_0928_stackOverflow_MyQuestion.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:21)
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\9.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\9.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

And please see message. Thank you guys!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaK7j.jpg

Comment: What's your expected output? What's the output of the code you have?

Comment: Hi, perhaps use `entry.getValue().get(0)` for the value part of your `toMap` function.

Comment: @Sweeper: The expected output should be to store the string "AAA" and double value of -5.6 saved to the HashMap<String, Double> queryPositions.

Because absolute value of (-5.6) is greater than 1.0.

Comment: @IronMan: Tried the suggestion, it doesn't work. Here's output so far.  Thank you both.

Comment: What should be the value of the final map? The first value of the list? Its absolute value? The sum of all the values of the list? Please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but there's no point in sorting the entries and then collecting to a default map (`HashMap`), which does not preserve insertion order. Also, why are you using `.distinct()`?

This is how I would do it:

```
Map<String, Double> queryPositions = sourceHashMapFind.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> Math.abs(e.getValue().get(0)) > 1.0)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue().get(0)));
```

This assumes that you want the first item of each list as the value of each entry of the new map.

If you need the entries sorted by key, you might want to create a `TreeMap`:

```
Map<String, Double> queryPositions = sourceHashMapFind.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> Math.abs(e.getValue().get(0)) > 1.0)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> e.getKey(), 
        e -> e.getValue().get(0),
        (oldValue, newValue) -> newValue,
        TreeMap::new)));
```

This uses the overloaded version of [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) that expects a factory for the map.

Comment: Hi fps, thank you very much!   To answer question, I am really a java newbie, thus used distinct().  Thank you once again!

Comment: @User `distinct()` is not needed, because you are streaming a map, and a map never has duplicate keys. Thus, you won't have duplicate keys in your final map, either